# Using Kubectl, how do you to start a Kubernetes watch at a specific resource version?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

To support efficient watch operations the Kubernetes API supports the `resourceVersion`and `resourceVersionMatch` parameters as seen [in the API documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#resource-versions). However, I do not see how you can do this with `kubectl`. Maybe I am missing something here but I would expect there to be something like `kubectl get jobs -n mynamespace -w -resourceVersion=24234` to start a watch at the given resource version. According to the API docs this is the efficient way of doing a watch operation. But I can't seem to find anything in the [kubectl docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get). Can someone please explain why `kubectl` does not support resource versions or how to accomplish it with `kubectl`?

Comment: Do you want (and know) a specific historical version, or do you just want to start watching from the present (`kubectl get deployment -w` to watch rollout progress, for example)?

Comment: @DavidMaze All of the API docs I have read say to use a resource version when using the REST API. I guess I am wondering why `kubectl` does not provide a resource version parameter if it is the "most efficient" way of doing a watch. Ideally I would have a resource version and be able to get all events that have happened since that version. Ultimately I am writing a program that does this with the REST API but I was wanting to see if I could do the same thing in `kubectl`.

Comment: Did you saw [this docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#generated-values) `resourceVersion: tracks the persisted version of the object`  Are you referring do the same resourceVersion? If you will edit any resources, like deployment they are changing also resourceVersion. Could you elaborate?

Comment: What about `kubectl get --raw`, as example `kubectl get --raw /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dtest-8656bc94b4-ssnkm&resourceVersion=4521069&watch=true` It would work for you, or you need something more?

Comment: resourceVersion helps to detect changes of an object configuration on a particular cluster. It only helps to determine if the certain object has changed since the previous check, when resourceVersion value was viewed and saved for the future comparison. It doesn't change incrementally and I wouldn't rely on it comparing objects on different clusters or using it as a version tracker. `kubectl replace` command requires that resourceVersion value stays the same for edited YAML and for the object in the cluster that should be replaced.